# exoPlatform, where to add LDAP functionality

Tags: maven, ldap, portal

I'm trying to understand how to implement the LDAP functionality with exoPlatform. I think the [documentation](https://docs.exoplatform.org/en/5.2/LDAP.html?highlight=ldap#quick-start) is quite extensive but I really don't understand how to get started.

I launched my docker images, exo and mySQL, thanks to [this tutorial](https://www.exoplatform.com/blog/2016/06/14/exo-platform-in-a-docker-container/) and I can access the exoPlatform homepage.

However, about the LDAP extension, I clearly don't know where to integrate the [config files](https://github.com/exo-samples/docs-samples/tree/master/ldap-extension) specified. Is it in the exo docker?